# Salesforce Test Class system.assert logs

Tags: apex, unit-test

Am I able to see the system.assert logs anywhere? I checked the logs after I run the test in my UAT org but i dont see the system.assert anywhere???

```
@isTest
public class testSFSETrigger {
public static void myTest() {
    Account a1 = new Account();
    a1.Name = 'Test Bill To';
    insert a1;

    Opportunity o1 = new Opportunity();
    o1.Name = 'test';
    o1.Account = a1.Id;
    insert o1;

    Contact c1 = new Contact();
    c1.FirstName = 'Steve';
    c1.LastName = 'Rogers';
    c1.AccountId = a1.Id;
    insert c1;


    //Insert 1 quote to satisfy first fork criteria
    //where myObject.Contact__c != null;
    SBQQ__Quote__c quote = new SBQQ__Quote__c();
    quote.Contact__c = c1.Id;
    insert quote;


    system.assert(quote.Contact__c != null, 'Contact not created');


    //Insert another quote to satisfy second fork criteria
    // where myObject.Contact__c == NULL
    // and  myObject.Opportunity2__c != null 
    SBQQ__Quote__c quote2 = new SBQQ__Quote__c();
    quote2.Opportunity2__c = o1.Id;
    insert quote2;


 system.assert(quote2.Opportunity2__c != null 'Opportunity not related');

}
}
```

Comment: This code wouldn't even compile. Do your tests run? Do they pass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**System.debug()** is for logging things that we need to see on debug logs (e.g. any message, object dump, etc.).

**System.assert()** is for proving our code behaves as expected.

It's better to use 2nd/3rd parameters to log any outputs too, so we have more information on possible issue if assert fails.
For example,

```
system.assert(quote.Contact__c != null, 'Contact not created, quote.Contact__c: '+quote.Contact__c);
```

We must include sufficient **System.assert()** methods to prove that code behaves properly, and also follow [Testing best practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dev_guide.htm) .

I personally prefer having System.debug() before assert.

Comment: That's what the assertion message (2nd/3rd param) is for; you don't typically need to debug before assert. Debug statements can get lost in the logs, but the assertion method is guaranteed to be seen.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox Yes, I agree with you. Probably it's my personal preference to have the values logged to specifically see in debug log regardless asserts failure. Updated answer accordingly.

Comment: Note also that if you are using a Logging framework (rather than system debug), you can make the third argument of system.assert: `... + MyLoggingFramework.getLog())` and then the assert includes the relevant details leading up to the assertion failure

Comment: @cropredy Excellent point. I don't suppose you have a favorite you'd like to share?

Comment: @sfdcfox - I'm using a modified version of the Andrew Fawcett [EventLogger with Platform Events](https://github.com/afawcett/eventlogging). I have to admit, I've been dilatory about contributing my enhancements to the lib so YMMV

Answer (score 2):

`system.assert` statements are different from `system.debug` statements.

`System.debug` will let you see the output from apex.

`System.assert` is used in test classes to make sure expected results match with actual outputs. When both match, the test class is said to be passed else failed. You can use it in regular apex to compare components of same type(integer vs integer, string vs string etc.)